# Unable to install Contrast-agent package on Poetry

Tags: python, docker, python-poetry, contrast

Getting the below error when I install contrast package using `poetry install` command:

`RuntimeError: Failed to build Contrast C extension. It is necessary for autotools (autoconf, automake) to be installed in order for Contrast to build properly. On lightweight systems such as Alpine, it may be necessary to install linux-headers if they are not available already. Some other systems may require "build essential" packages to be installed.`

Can someone help me how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Have you followed the advice in the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by using the below commands since I was running this on Ubuntu the below commands fixed the issue for me. Once these commands were run I was able to add contrast-agent in poetry and then `poetry install` ran successfully for me

```
apt update
apt upgrade -y
apt install linux-libc-dev
apt-get install autoconf -y
apt-get install automake 
apt-get install build-essential -y
```